# Qt Creator, ptrace: Operation not permitted. What is the permanent solution?

Tags: c++, qt, linux-kernel, qt5, linux-mint

While debugging `C++` code in Qt creator I get the following error

```
ptrace: Operation not permitted.

Could not attach to the process. Make sure no other debugger traces this process.
Check the settings of
/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

Here a temporary solution is found: [Receiving error while trying to debug in QtProject](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244336/receiving-error-while-trying-to-debug-in-qtproject)

- temporary solution (won't survive a reboot):

  `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`

But it is difficult to run the same code in terminal every time when I start my PC to use Qt.

```
What is the permanent solution for this?
```

Comment: You could just add it to autostart (e.g. put it in `/etc/rc.local`).

Comment: Just remove sudo. `/etc/rc.local` is executed with superuser rights.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/311053/how-to-make-ip-forwarding-permanent

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If running Ubuntu,

The recommended way to enable the needed ptrace kernel setting (hinted by qtcreator) is to edit  /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

```
sudo vim  /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

Then change

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
```

to

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

Save,

then apply:

```
$ sudo sysctl --system -a -p|grep yama
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

run

```
man sysctl
```

for more info.

Comment: this is the most correct answer! though the accepted answer will work, it is a hack, and changing this setting in the sysctl config is a much better option.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem while OP's one time solution is the only thing that works for me, but sadly jsut until enxt restart.....

Answer (score 24):

I got the answer.

- Go to the location `/etc` with root privilege.
- Find the file `rc.local`.
- Open it in a text editor like gedit and add the following    code
  there
- `echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`

Restart your pc and you can see the debugger working perfectly.

Comment: `sudo ~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator`, and no need to modifies the files mentioned.

Comment: Brilliant. Fixed mine too. Nice one

Comment: Instead of rebooting you can also execute the command once in terminal:

```echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope```

Comment: @Life: this is probably a workaround. But the disadvantage is that you give root rights to your `qtcreator`. If there is a bug in `qtcreator` or a hacker finds an exploit, he/she has access rights to your entire machine. People should be more careful when it comes to `sudo`.

Comment: @Life: ***do not suggest that***. Ever. It's a security issue, not to mention that any Qt application using Qt >= 5.3 will happily `abort()` if run them with EUID 0 (see [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/74531/)). -1 the main answer because the proper solution is modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf` or the right file under `/etc/sysctl.d/`, and *not* adding random stuff in the init sequence.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer that works for me on ubuntu in below link and the credit goes to [dstzcxr](https://askubuntu.com/users/298229/dstzcxr)

https://askubuntu.com/a/501271/395583

> Just uncheck (or check - run - uncheck if it is for some reason
>   unchecked) the box "Run in terminal" in "Projects" (on the left bar) -
>   "Run" tab - "Run" section.

Comment: The only thing that changed to me is, that now the terminal app doesn't start even anymore.

Comment: You can find the output of your program in the "application output" in the bottom beside to Issues. If that's not what you are looking for, please explain your question in more details .

Comment: my problem is the same as the OP and it simply just doesn't make my programm start anymore.

Comment: is there a way to fix it on Android OS? i want to debug an app with GDB but it gives me "ptrace: Operation not permitted" error