# setcap preventing debugging from within Qt Creator

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator

While debugging C++ code in Qt creator I get the following error

> ptrace: Operation not permitted.
>
> Could not attach to the process. Make sure no other debugger traces
> this process. If your uid matches the uid of the target process, check
> the settings of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope For more details,
> see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

I have a custom CMake command after the target builds that adds capabilities to the executable in order to use functions from a 3rd party library I link with:

```
add_custom_command( TARGET TARGNAME
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND echo PW | sudo --stdin setcap CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_IPC_OWNER,CAP_SYS_RAWIO=ep TARGOUTNAME
    WORKING_DIRECTORY $<TARGET_PROPERTY:iVn,RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>
    VERBATIM )
```

I have tried the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120711/qt-creator-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-what-is-the-permanent-solution), but nothing I've tried has made a difference. Also, I only get the above error when I choose to attach the debugger to the already running process.

When I choose the "Start debugging of startup project" option, the error does not appear. However, that causes calls to the 3rd party library in my application to fail.